# Refactoring Dictionary into ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Currently I have some async methods that all trying to update and read from a Dictionary

Side question:
Can the async functions cause KeyNotFoundException and NullReferenceException?
I am just doing 
`_dictonary[myString] = myObject`

Anyways. I would like to replace all `Dictionary<string,object>` with `ConcurrentDictionary<string, object`> . I don't care at all whether some thread get the data right before/after another thread write into it.

Is there any trouble I can get into if I just do a text replace all `Dictionary` with `ConcurrentDictionary` and it compiles successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally `ConcurrentDictionary`'s [indexer method](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L873-L890) uses `TryGetValue` and the same `TryAddInternal` as `TryAdd` does.

Setting a value shouldn't throw an exception unless your key is null. It should work as you expect (although another thread could come in and change it before you read it again).

You will still get a `KeyNotFoundException` if the key isn't found in the dictionary. There could be timing issues if you expect one thread to insert a value, and then you try and read it using `concurrentDictionary[key]`. I'd recommend using `TryGetValue` if you want safety in this respect.